# Rails system tests unable to load a lib file required in a model, file loads fine in development, how can I fix this?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, capybara, minitest, ruby-on-rails-6.1, load-path

*(From chapter 14 in 'Agile Web Development with Rails 6')*
I am trying to run a system test which touches a model which requires a file from the /lib directory. The file loads fine and the code works fine on localhost in development mode, but as soon as I run the test it errors with:

```
Error:
OrdersTest#test_visiting_the_index:
DRb::DRbRemoteError: cannot load such file -- pago (LoadError)
    app/models/order.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Excerpt from the model, `order.rb`, that requires the file is:

```
require "pago"

class Order < ApplicationRecord
    enum pay_type: {
        "Cheque"                    => 0,
        "Credit card"           => 1,
        "Purchase order"    => 2
    }
    has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
    
    validates :name, :address, :email, presence: true
    validates :pay_type, inclusion: pay_types.keys
    
    def add_line_items_from_cart(cart)
        cart.line_items.each do |item|
            item.cart_id = nil
            line_items << item
        end
    end

    def charge!(pay_type_params)
        payment_details = {}
        payment_method = nil

        case pay_type
        when "Cheque"
            payment_method = :cheque
            payment_details[:routing] = pay_type_params[:routing_number]
            payment_details[:account] = pay_type_params[:account_number]
        when "Credit card"
            payment_method = :credit_card
            month,year = pay_type_params[:expiration_date].split(//)
            payment_details[:cc_num] = pay_type_params[:credit_card_number]
            payment_details[:expiration_month] = month
            payment_details[:expiration_year] = year
        when "Purchase order"
            payment_method = :po
            payment_details[:po_num] = pay_type_params[:po_number]
        end

        payment_result = Pago.make_payment(
            order_id: id,
            payment_method: payment_method,
            payment_details: payment_details
        )

        if payment_result.succeeded?
            OrderMailer.received(self).deliver_later
        else
            raise payment_result.error
        end
    end
end
```

Excerpt from the actual `/lib/pago.rb`:

```
require "ostruct"

class Pago
  
  def self.make_payment(order_id:,
                        payment_method:,
                        payment_details:)
    case payment_method
    when :cheque
      Rails.logger.info "Processing cheque: " +
        payment_details.fetch(:routing).to_s + "/" + 
        payment_details.fetch(:account).to_s
    when :credit_card
      Rails.logger.info "Processing credit_card: " +
        payment_details.fetch(:cc_num).to_s + "/" + 
        payment_details.fetch(:expiration_month).to_s + "/" + 
        payment_details.fetch(:expiration_year).to_s
    when :po
      Rails.logger.info "Processing purchase order: " +
        payment_details.fetch(:po_num).to_s
    else
      raise "Unknown payment_method #{payment_method}"
    end
    sleep 3 unless Rails.env.test?
    Rails.logger.info "Done Processing Payment"
    OpenStruct.new(succeeded?: true)
  end
end
```

The test file that I', trying to run:
`test/system/orders_test.rb`

```
require "application_system_test_case"

class OrdersTest < ApplicationSystemTestCase
  include ActiveJob::TestHelper
  setup do
    @order = orders(:one)
  end

  test "visiting the index" do
    visit orders_url
    assert_selector "h1", text: "Orders"
  end

  test "destroying an Order" do
    visit orders_url
    page.accept_confirm do
      click_on "Destroy", match: :first
    end

    assert_text "Order was successfully destroyed"
  end

  test "check full payment with cheque flow" do
    LineItem.delete_all
    Order.delete_all

    visit store_index_url

    click_on 'Add to cart', match: :first

    click_on 'Checkout'

    fill_in 'order_name', with: 'Dave Thomas'
    fill_in 'order_address', with: '123 Main Street'
    fill_in 'order_email', with: 'dave@example.com'

    assert_no_selector "#order_routing_number"

    select 'Cheque', from: 'Pay type'
    fill_in 'Routing #', with: '123456'
    fill_in 'Account #', with: '678901'

    assert_selector "#order_routing_number"
    assert_selector "#order_account_number"

    perform_enqueued_jobs { click_button 'Place order' }
    
    orders = Order.all
    assert_equal 1, orders.size
    order = orders.first

    assert_equal 'Dave Thomas',       order.name
    assert_equal '123 Main Street',   order.address
    assert_equal 'dave@example.com',  order.email
    assert_equal 'Cheque',            order.pay_type 
    assert_equal 1, order.line_items.size     

    mail = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
    assert_equal ['dave@example.com'],    mail.to
    assert_equal 'James Kemp<from@example.com>', mail[:from].value
    assert_equal 'Order received; thanks', mail.subject
  end


  test "check CC number for credit card payment choice" do
    visit store_index_url

    click_on 'Add to cart', match: :first

    click_on 'Checkout'

    fill_in 'order_name', with: 'Dave Thomas'
    fill_in 'order_address', with: '123 Main Street'
    fill_in 'order_email', with: 'dave@example.com'

    assert_no_selector "#order_credit_card_number"
    assert_no_selector "#order_expiration_date"

    select 'Credit card', from: 'Pay type'

    assert_selector "#order_credit_card_number"
    assert_selector "#order_expiration_date"
  end

  test "check PO number for purchase order payment choice" do
    visit store_index_url

    click_on 'Add to cart', match: :first

    click_on 'Checkout'

    fill_in 'order_name', with: 'Dave Thomas'
    fill_in 'order_address', with: '123 Main Street'
    fill_in 'order_email', with: 'dave@example.com'

    assert_no_selector "#order_po_number"

    select 'Purchase order', from: 'Pay type'

    assert_selector "#order_po_number"
  end

end
```

If i run rails console `require 'pago'` returns true. I don't see any clues in the various config and environment files as to what the problem might be. The tutorial code seems to be char by char the same as mine. I just can't work out what's oging wrong here. Can anyone help?

My Gemfile FYI (I have bundle installed):

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '3.0.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: 'main'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.4', '>= 6.1.4.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  # Display performance information such as SQL time and flame graphs for each request in your browser.
  # Can be configured to work on production as well see: https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler/blob/master/README.md
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 3.26'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: What command are you using to run the test?

Comment: `bin/rails test test/system/orders_test.rb`

Comment: I came back to my code today with no changes having been made to codebase, the only thing I'd done was shut down and restart my local machine, for this error to have disappeared. So switching computer on and off solved this problem!Any guesses as to what may have changed to make this error go away? Something environment wise that got reset perhaps?